# String? for C# in method

Tags: c#

I would like to have something like tkis "int?" but for string. You know if I will not give data to parameter I will not got error. I need some idea to this problem.

```
Example(4);

public void Example(int, string?){}
```

For all of you I give points. Thanks for help. Topic [closed] :)

Comment: String are nullable by default that's why there is no need for `string?`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't available as `string` is already a reference type, so is already nullable. The `?` suffix is syntactic sugar for [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), so `int?` is equivalent to `Nullable<int>`... and `Nullable<T>` has a constraint of `where T : struct`, i.e. `T` has to be a non-nullable value type... which excludes `string`.

In other words, you can just write

```
public void Example(int x, string y)
{
    if (y == null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this is different from making it an optional parameter. Passing in a `null` value is still passing in a value. If you want to make it an optional parameter you can do that too:

```
public void Example(int x, string y = "Fred")

...

Example(10); // Equivalent to Example(10, "Fred");
```

Comment: Jon for your example you can also write `if (x == null)` but with a warning :)

Answer (score 4):

In C# 4.0 you can use optional parameters by writing

```
public void Example (int a, string b = null) {}
```

Otherwise, you can overload the method

```
public void Example (int a) {}
public void Example (int a, string b) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

string type take null by default and you do not need to make it nullable as it is already reference type. You can use it this way.

```
public void Example(int i, string s)
{

}
```

Call it with null will be

```
Example(null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

System.String is a reference type, so you can assign to a String variable null without declaring the variable nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to give the string argument a default value?

e.g.

```
Example(4);

public void Example(int x, string y = null)
{
    // etc
}
```